# Mosfet drive for inverting buck boost converter

Tags: driver, buck-boost

I'm working on an inverting buck boost circuit for university and have come up with the following schematic. I'm ordering quite expensive parts so I wanted to get some opinions and advice as to whether it will succeed in driving the mosfet as is!

Another idea I had was to create a rail 15 volts higher than the +15v in and to get a low side driver with sufficient voltage capability, to simplify the design. This circuit is one phase in a three phase converter, so the additional rail would not increase the component count much. I realise I may have to replace the output diode for a low side mosfet to achieve this, but that hopefully should be easier to drive. Would this be a good way to go perhaps?

I want to avoid using a p-ch mosfet also as I'm aiming for 15 amps per phase.
Thanks for any suggestions!

[image: Buck boost driver]

Comment: Just about all the parts there are redundant (save the topology elements). Unless you have a specific reason why you'd want to do a (relative) discrete approach, there shouldn't be any reason why you wouldn't want a dedicated IC for this. There are even multi-phase controllers.

Comment: Fair enough, unfortunately my lecturer would fail me! Do you see problems here?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using this topology? Is there a special requirement that forces you to use this schematic, as opposed to another one? Do you have to build a supply *like this*, or just a buck-boost? The part that confuses me most is "*I'm ordering quite **expensive** parts so I wanted to get some opinions and advice as to whether it will succeed in driving the mosfet* **as is**".

Comment: I do need to build an inverting buck-boost of exactly this type which is controlled by a pic mcu, I should have specified a controller sorry. So a dedicated ic is definitely out. As for driving the fets, I'm totally free to choose, that's pretty much the purpose of this exercise - how to drive the gate with these negative and positive source pin voltages. I would like to keep this arangement generally, just to be able to solve this particular problem! Thanks..

Comment: I see a battery on the output, is this meant to be a charger? Also, I don't really understand the purpose of `Q2`.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me!! It's meant to be a battery charger, yes, controlled by the PIC, but once it puts out 17V that's fine for the moment. Q2 is a level shifter, it takes the system ground referenced logic pwm 0-5vs and translates it to -17 to -10 volts or so. The level shifter seems to work great on the breadboard.

Comment: I'm confused, overall: why does the output serve as the reference for the whole schematic, why use a level shifter, why a floating driver, where is the current sense if this is a charger? All you need is a PMOS and a level shifter from 5 V to 15 V (between the uC and the PMOS), that serves as a driver, too. What you did there is very convoluted.

Comment: I referenced to the negative output so that the driver common pin could be tied there, to hold Q1 open. Using a pmos is of course much simpler, but since I'm hoping to drive considerable current I don't want to be battling the rds on from the outset. There is current sensing at both output and input, using ina240 and .001 ohm resistors as well as voltage feedback, I didn't include much of the circuit here.. it wasn't my intention to over complicate things, but that negative voltage is troublesome..

Comment: Think a bit of what you're achieving: you have a battery charger, which means the output voltage is *variable*, and that serves as a *reference* ground for the rest of the circuitry. Your output is your ground. It also looks like this approach means a lot to you.

Comment: This approach only means a lot to me because it's the task I've been set, it's a learning exercise. The output voltage only serves as a reference for the mosfet driver, system ground is 0v and is the reference for the mcu. I cannot see how else you can provide the -17 volts required to turn off the mosfet when the inductor / fet source / cathode node drops to this level. Can we just focus on this precise question? How would you drive this mosfet yourself given the source voltage will swing from -17 to +16v?